# Creating a GUI Update Thread

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have created a custom ArrayAdapter that displays a listview with images, text, and a data field that can be updated by modifying a set of global variables. I can initialize the interface and verify that by changing the global variables I can change the listview, but only from within OnCreate(). As such, I have tried creating a thread to update the listview every 200ms using notifyDataSetChanged(), but I cannot seem to start the thread. Trying to call `.start();` creates an error that states "The method start() is undefined for the type MainActivity". Any help would be appreciated.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    // Sensor Constants
    public static String temperature;
    public static String humidity;
    public static String lpg;
    public static String alcohol;
    public static int temperature_int;
    public static int humidity_int;
    public static int lpg_int;
    public static int alcohol_int;


    // Layout
    ListView listView;
    ItemAdapter adapter;


    // USB
    UsbManager USB_Manager;
    UsbDevice Sense;
    PendingIntent permission;
    IntentFilter filter;
    //BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    //USBBuffer_s_received_data = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Initialize Interface
        Model.LoadModel();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] ids = new String[Model.Items.size()];
        for (int i= 0; i < ids.length; i++)
        {ids[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);}
        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, ids);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //USB
        if ((UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) != null)
        {
            USB_Manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
            if (USB_Manager.getDeviceList().values().iterator().next() != null)
            {
                Sense = USB_Manager.getDeviceList().values().iterator().next();
                if ((UsbDevice) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE) != null)
                {
                    Sense = (UsbDevice) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                }
            }
        }


        // Update Layout
        temperature_int = 30; humidity_int = 6; lpg_int = 5000; alcohol_int = 500;
        temperature = String.valueOf(temperature_int);
        humidity = String.valueOf(humidity_int);
        lpg = String.valueOf(lpg_int);
        alcohol = String.valueOf(alcohol_int);


        Model.LoadModel();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        GUI_Update();
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void GUI_Update()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                        Model.LoadModel();
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        //.start();
    }
```

**EDIT**
Moving the location of .start() fixed the problem but now the application exits immediately upon launch and I am not sure why. This is the error log that I get..

```
12-20 17:22:11.010: D/libEGL(15395): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
12-20 17:22:11.010: D/libEGL(15395): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
12-20 17:22:11.018: D/libEGL(15395): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
12-20 17:22:11.096: D/OpenGLRenderer(15395): Enabling debug mode 0
12-20 17:22:11.369: W/dalvikvm(15395): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4198ac68)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-711
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395): Process: com.byrdonatwigge.sense, PID: 15395
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6094)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:857)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4320)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10942)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10897)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:201)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:344)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setVisible(Drawable.java:575)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.widget.ImageView.onDetachedFromWindow(ImageView.java:1243)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:12627)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2585)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout(ViewGroup.java:4027)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1924)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:521)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at com.byrdonatwigge.sense.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:445)
12-20 17:22:11.377: E/AndroidRuntime(15395):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-20 17:22:12.127: D/AndroidRuntime(15395): Shutting down VM
12-20 17:22:12.127: W/dalvikvm(15395): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4198ac68)
12-20 17:22:12.127: I/Process(15395): Sending signal. PID: 15395 SIG: 9
```

**EDIT #2**
**Update Thread**

```
private void GUI_Update()
    {
        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                Model.LoadModel();
                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

**Log**

```
12-20 18:49:49.741: D/dalvikvm(17054): Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-20 18:49:50.085: D/libEGL(17054): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
12-20 18:49:50.092: D/libEGL(17054): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
12-20 18:49:50.100: D/libEGL(17054): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
12-20 18:49:50.186: D/OpenGLRenderer(17054): Enabling debug mode 0
12-20 18:50:09.405: D/AndroidRuntime(17117): Shutting down VM
12-20 18:50:09.405: W/dalvikvm(17117): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4198ac68)
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117): Process: com.byrdonatwigge.sense, PID: 17117
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117):    at com.byrdonatwigge.sense.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:449)
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-20 18:50:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(17117):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move `.start()` before the last `)` for the `Thread` constructor

```
public void GUI_Update()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    Model.LoadModel();
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();  // here
```

That should make it run. However, I'm not sure why you want to do this. Changing it every 200ms is very fast and I'm not sure what you plan to accomplish with this. Also, having an infinite `loop` is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. And you are correct; this is just a rough draft of the code. However, now the application exits immediately upon launch, and I am not sure why. I have updated my original post with the log

Comment: What is line 445 of `MainActivity`?

Comment: line 445 is: ``listView.setAdapter(adapter);``

Comment: Ah, yes, because you are updating a `UI` element on a background `Thread`. You would need to do that in `runOnUiThread()`

Comment: Okay I have modified my code to use the runOnUithread, but the application still seems to exit upon launch. I have posted the log. Thanks

Comment: Line 449 is: ``adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();``

Comment: Well that is what I am confused about because I can call ``adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`` from withing ``OnCreate()`` but when I try and call it from the thread it throws a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: I tried setting breakpoints but I cannot seem to figure out why there is a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to post a Runnable object to the original thread in order to achieve this.
But this is a way more complicated solution. (Use it only if you cant to keep the same approach due to other reasons)
Use a [TimeTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) instead. It would serve your purpose in a much cleaner and simpler way.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a thread if you just need to schedule something to happen in the future.

A simple class which is unfortunately not perfect for your usecase is Android's [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). It allows you to schedule repeated events until the limit is reached. You might be able to use that with some sort of infinite limit.

You can on the other hand use a slightly modified version that is based on `Handler`. A `Handler` can schedule events that happen within the UI thread.

```
public abstract class Ticker {
    private final long mPeriod;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public Ticker(long period) {
        mPeriod = period;
    }

    public final void start() {
        stop();
        mHandler.post(mTick);
    }

    public final void stop() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTick);
    }

    private final Runnable mTick = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mTick, mPeriod);
            onTick();
        }
    };

    /** Called every period ms */
    public abstract void onTick();
}


public class Foo extends Activity {

    private Ticker mTicker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mTicker = new Ticker(200) {
            @Override
            public void onTick() {
                // update things
            }
        };
        mTicker.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mTicker.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run code on the main thread, this is the simplest solution I've found. Any time you want to update the UI, it HAS to be on the main thread or else it will fail or do nothing.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code to run on main thread
    }
})
```